# how to use object in pipe async and in component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I need to use the reference of observable twice.
in html:

```
<div *ngIf="subject$ | async as subject">
```

and in template:

```
this.subject = subject
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`.pipe()`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#piping) to pipe the data, then use [`tap()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) to extract the value into a variable that exists within the component.

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="subject$ | async as subject">
      <!-- do something with "subject" -->
      <span>{{subject.someProp}}</span>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  // Used within the typescript
  subject = '';

  // Used within the html
  // Assuming data is retrieved through some sort of service
  subject$ = this.service.getData().pipe(
    tap(i => this.subject = i)
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the value in you code, you need to subscribe

```js
this.subject$.subscribe((value) => this.subject = value);
```

I guess, that this was your intenion; but the alias `as subject` only exists inside the tag it was defined.

You should use the [`share()`Operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) to ensure you do not trigger something twice (like a server request):

```js
private subject$ = new Subject<any>();
public observable$ = this.subject$.map(share());
```

additional benefit is that `observable` is now an `Observable` which can not be used to emit a new value at the "consuming code".

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully, this solution can help you to understand how to use observable twice https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jgcgnf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Don't just post links to your code. Also post the related code in the answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I just share link of project, let me edit the link. Thanks for correcting